# Bounding the integral $\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\cos y}{\sqrt{(2\cos y + x -2)^2+ 4(x-3)}} dy $ from below

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

Please help me bound this integral,

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\cos y}{\sqrt{(2\cos y + x -2)^2+ 4(x-3)}} dy $$

I've hit a speed bump in some of my work, I need to prove that $|f(x)| > 0$ as long as $x \not\in [-6,3]$. I've put it into the computer and it seems that $|f(x)|$ decays to zero like $x^{-1/2}$ but I haven't been able to prove anything concrete.

Trying to use the symmetries of cosine, the reverse Holder's inequality, expanding the $\cos y$ term in the numerator as a series, and putting it into a CAS have all gotten me nowhere. Any help is greatly appreciated!